# SOQL or Report to identify the number of accounts without an opportunity closed within a year

Tags: apex, soql, reporting, account, closedate

I wanted to quickly identify which accounts have not been closed within a year. However the following will always return too many rows queried 50,000+.

Is there a way to get a list of these records programatically or even better using a report? Thanks.

```
set<Id> accountIds = new set<Id>();

for(Opportunity o : [select id, accountid from Opportunity where CloseDate < LAST_N_DAYS:365 and StageName = 'Closed Won - Order']){
    accountIds.add(o.accountid);
}
//shows me the number of accounts that have 
system.debug('size1= '+accountIds.size());

for(Opportunity o2 : [select id, accountid from Opportunity where CloseDate >= LAST_N_DAYS:365 and StageName = 'Closed Won - Order']){
    //removes the recent accounts from the set
    accountIds.remove(o2.accountid);
}

//shows me the count of the final number of accounts that haven't closed within a year
system.debug('size2= '+accountIds.size());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Off the top of my head (for your "Even better, a report")

1. Create a Roll Up Summary formula field on the account
2. Have it get the max date from closed/won Opportunities

Then use that field in a report of your choosing. You could use a filter in the reports that says the field from #1 is < THIS_YEAR or < THIS_QUARTER, you get the idea

Answer (score 5):

If you want to find records which were closed *within the last 365 days* (`2016-02-08` through `2017-02-08`), use:

```
WHERE CloseDate = LAST_N_DAYS:365
```

When you filter with `<`, you look for anything *before* that range, so all records closed before `2016-02-08`.

If you want to find records which were closed *last year* (`2016-01-01` through `2016-12-31`), use:

```
WHERE CloseDate = LAST_YEAR
```

If you want to get `Account` records with such `Opportunity` children, you'll want a **[`Left Inner Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Inner_Join)**:

```
SELECT AccountNumber FROM Account WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity
    WHERE CloseDate = LAST_YEAR
)
```

This inner-join sub-select ***will not count against your query rows limit***.

The SOQL approach is flexible in that you choose a range to fit your needs. There are a lot of date filters available, for example you could filter specifically 2015:

```
SELECT AccountNumber FROM Account WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity
    WHERE CALENDAR_YEAR(CloseDate) = 2015
)
```

Have a read through **[Date Formats and Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)** for a complete understanding of the date filter aspect of this problem.

Comment: +1 for the Filter query and pointing out it does not count agains rows retuned limit. Very important point to remember